# select2 problem when letting users search options and enter their custom value

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I have used `select2` for my select options to let users search options and enter their custom value if needed. Now I have 2 problems.
1- It shows whatever I search as an option as below. Is there a way to remove the search history?

[image]

2- Sometimes I type a new option and and press enter key but it doesn't show the custom value. The search box becomes empty.

[image]

My code:

```
 <select class="form-control" type="text" id="title" name="title">
       <option value=""></option>
       @foreach($titles as $title)
       <option value="{{ $title }}">{{ $title }}</option>
       @endforeach
 </select>

 $("#title").select2({
       tags: true
  });
```

Comment: I use select2 in just the same way and it works fine. So I guess we need your code to find any issuee

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff I Edited the post and added my code.

Comment: the option value has to be a unique id. So if you provide it with the same title multiple times it will not work

Comment: the value is unique